# How do I change the SIM card out of a Lumia 820?

Tags: nokia-lumia-820, sim

I've got a second hand Nokia Lumia 820 that I want to use for testing, but I can't figure out how to get my SIM card into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the [user guide](http://nds1.nokia.com/phones/files/pdf_guides/devices/Lumia820/Nokia_Lumia_820_UG_en.pdf) as a PDF. On page 7 of the linked guide you can see how to change the SIM card. Nokia suggests prying open the shell by putting your thumbnail in the seam between the screen frame and the
back cover, then bending the cover until it opens. A blunt knife might be helpful if you have troubles prying it open with your fingers.